# probability of receive n packets under x mintues

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Assume we have a server, the time between two packets received by our server is defined as exponential distributed with intensity   $\lambda=2 \text{ packets}/10 \text{ mins}$

Now calculate the probability that the time from $X$(random time) until the next packet-received, is $5$ minutes or longer?

We that we can model waiting time as exponential function, therefore we get

$f(t)= (1/10)*e^{-t/10}$

Now we need to find out the probability that the time from $X$(random time) until the next packet-received, is 5 minutes or longer?

We integrate $f(t)$ and get $[e^{-t/10}]$ but i am not sure how to choose my limits ?

Am I thinking right here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are thinking correctly, but there was a slight error.  The intensity here is $\frac{1}{5}$, not $\frac{1}{10}$  Let $T$ be the wait time.  We know that $T$ is exponential with intensity $\lambda$.  This means that $$\mathbb{P}(T \geq 5) = \int\limits_{5}^\infty \frac{1}{5}\cdot e^{-t/5} dt = -e^{-t/5}\bigg|_{5}^\infty = e^{-1}. $$

---

EDIT: If you're looking for $\mathbb{P}(T_1 + T_2 + T_3 < 60)$, you need to integrate: $$\int\limits_{0}^{60} \int\limits_{0}^{60 - t_3}\int\limits_{0}^{60 - t_3 - t_2} \frac{1}{5^3} e^{-(t_1 + t_2 +t_3)/5^3}dt_1dt_2dt_3. $$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! i double checked it with other sources and seems to be true :) . btw if i want to find the probability for reciving more than 3 packs under one hour(60 min), then i only need change the limits to $[0,60]$ right?

Comment: actually i am abit confused about how to approch the second question, not sure if i even can use the same forumla

Comment: @dumble24, This second question is a bit more complicated.  You now have three times, $T_1,T_2,T_3$,  that are independent and exponential with intensity $\lambda$; you want to find $\mathbb{P}(T_1 + T_2 + T_3 < 60)$.  You'll have to perform a triple integral here.

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by triple integral ?

Comment: could you please set up the integrals for me, then i can continue :)

Comment: @dumble24, I wrote the integral for you, but you should try to see why it works.

Comment: thanks !!! btw and if i want to find the probability for more than 4 packets then i 4 integrals, is that correct?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$